# How to use conditional formatting to search a specific value in a range in ms excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have values in the range *K5:K333*. I want the value in cell *S5* be searched in the range and the corresponding cells of the range being formatted.

I am using conditional formatting's *"use a formula to determine which cell to format"* feature.

I am selecting the range and putting this formula in the formula bar of conditional formatting `=NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($S$5, K5)))`.

The formula is working but it is giving a bit problem also, as there are values for example: *1000*, *10000*, *100000* in the range *K5:K333* and if in *S5* is the value 10 then it will highlight (format) *1000*, *10000* and *100000* also.

It should **only** format the exact value in cell *S5*.

The image below shows the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula `=EXACT($S$5, K5)` instead of `SEARCH`.

EXACT makes an exact comparison. SEARCH is useful to search a string inside another, that's why you are getting all those fake results.

Comment: +1. `EXACT()` isn't seen much in the wild, however be aware it's case sensitive, so if you don't need that level of precision you can simply use `=K5=$S$5`.